# How to setup Firebase rules for null checks

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to set up some firebase code to check for certain nodes having null values. not doing this already has given me some trouble, and I would like to know how to solve this!

I have tried this code:

```
  "rules": {
    "products": {
 // ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['title', 'description','price',
 //  'category', 'location', 'name', 'date', 
 //    'userID', 'userEmail', 'imagePath', 'imageUrl'])",
 ".indexOn" : ["title","category"],
 },
".read": "auth != null",
".write":"auth!=null"
```

but that does not seem to work.

my database has this structure:

```
products 
    |--productID
         |--title
         |--description
         |--price
         |--category
```

Comment: Unclear what "does not seem to work" here. Realtime database is schemaless. Any record that doesn't exist is the same as null. The .validate() rule would work as you've written it. (if it weren't commented out). Be more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry, sometimes a product is uploaded with null values. I want to have a check in place where it checks for any of the values being null. there may be some additional info in the post but these can be null. when using the commented code the upload failed. should it be something like products > productID > .validate() or what i have now like products > validate?

Comment: You can't validate a null value. That is the same as a non-existent value in RTDB. But .validate rules should work fine for your case (nulls are ignored). You obviously don't want to newData.hasChildren() for optional fields. Note that you can put the .validate rules at the specific fields as well.